how to still be able access data while hiding the inputs
when form is submitted and inputs were hidden like setting its display to none, the data cant be accessed right? like its not submitted with the form, now what should be my approach that if inputs were hidden i can still send the data via form or is accessible

setting its display to none, the data cant be accessed right wrong - however, with asp.net hidden means the element is not even present on the page

really? i thought that when setting the inputs display, like example, from block to none, the data could not sent with the form

I may be wrong (it happens) ... I usually use <input type="hidden"/> for hidden inputs

display: none is just cosmetic. it means that it is not visible but it is a pure styling implementation. AS such it remains in the DOM and as such can also be accessed.

Here you have an example with five different input elements. test1 in just a plain, test2 and test3 styled so that they are not showing, test4 is disabled, but still showing and test5 has the type of hidden.
When submitting the form, the only input field that is not included is the one (test4) that is disabled.


document.forms.form01.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  let data = new FormData(e.target);
  console.log(...data);
});
<form name="form01">
  <input type="text" name="test1" value="Test 1">
  <input type="text" name="test2" value="Test 2" style="display:none">
  <input type="text" name="test3" value="Test 3" style="visibility:hidden">
  <input type="text" name="test4" value="Test 4" disabled>
  <input type="hidden" name="test5" value="Test 5">
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>




@Cypher Look in the dev tools of your browser what is send to the server in the POST request. What happens when the request is received by asp.net server I don't know.
